# How can I remove duplication from TestCaseSource attribute in NUnit?

Tags: nunit

I have multiple test classes that have the same TestCaseSource parameters being passed in. The reason that I have multiple test classes is for parallelization of tests, which can only be done at the class level in NUnit. So, When I create a new class, I have to keep copying the line of code. I wonder if there is some way to remove this duplication.

```
[TestCaseSource(typeof(VisualValidationDataGetter), nameof(TestDataGetter.VisualValidation.GetDataByBlockCode),
            new object[] { ItemType })]
        public void VisualValidationTestMethod(VisualValidationCsvRecord testData)
        {
            PerformStepsForVisualValidation(studentData);
        }
```

I have about 10 such test classes with a call to this test method and these TestCaseSource properties. The only thing that changes is ItemType, which is defined at the class level. Every test class has a different ItemType, which resukts in different test data.  Is it possible to just call a test method and not have to keep repeating the call to this TestCaseSource line:

```
[TestCaseSource(typeof(VisualValidationDataGetter), nameof(TestDataGetter.VisualValidation.GetDataByBlockCode),
    new object[] { ItemType })]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear from the question what is the source of the duplication: why do you have 10 separate test cases which have the same TestCaseSource? Can't they all be refactored to one, parameterized, test case? Maybe you should add more details?

Comment: @amittai thank you, I have updated the question to reflect your concerns

Comment: From what I read you could use the [Parallelizable] attribute on a test case, can it solve your issue? see here: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Framework-Parallel-Test-Execution

Comment: Parallelization isn't the problem, the problem is the repeating call to this line below in 10 different classes:      [TestCaseSource(typeof(VisualValidationDataGetter), nameof(TestDataGetter.VisualValidation.GetDataByBlockCode),
    new object[] { ItemType })]